# What is the important dll files to execute any Qt5 application on any platform (Runtime files dll)?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qt5

I have created a simple application in `Qt5` but, when run that application in for example windows 7, tells me the dll file something is missing, and another dll and another dll.

Now I want a package that contain all dll files that any Qt application needed.
Or, What's the Important dll files that needed to work any Qt application ?

Comment: Which dlls exactly are missing?

Comment: @Laszlo Papp: I'm talking in general, I want a package that contain all dll files that any Qt application needed.

Comment: then the question becomes too broad with a lot of options, and hence might be closed. It would depend on a lot of factors, how you configure Qt, what kind of applications you are creating, what libraries you are using, which OS, which distribution, etc... I would suggest to specify the question.

Comment: @Laszlo Papp: I ask this question because any Qt application need many dll's files in order to work, It makes no sense to collect all dll's files in order to that application works. and for that reason I ask this question to get a package that contain all dll's that any qt application needed.

Comment: I am afraid that might be incorrect. I personally deployed many Qt applications to several clients without "many dlls". Writing an answer covering each case would be too lengthy IMHO.

Comment: Is this still unresolved one year later??

Answer (score 3):

> Or, What's the Important dll files that needed to work any Qt application ?

In general, the Qt modules that you are using. If you use QtSql, you need to have the corresponding dll, but it goes the same way for any module. As for a simple core application, you would need to have the QtCore dll, respectively. I could continue the enumeration, but I believe you see the pattern how it goes.

Going even a bit further, you would need to specify your dependencies in the `LIBS` variable if you happen to use qmake. That is also a place where you would already need to be aware of your direct dependencies.

It would be usually the single library name, but in complex cases, you can always read the documentation of the project. The main point is the fact that you need to get aware of this without debugging. The latter would be more like an after-thought.

There are no "hidden dependencies". Since you are coding the project, you know the dependencies that you use. You will need to ship them.

There are some odd and rare cases when issues come that you would not be aware of, like missing dll for a different machine having a distinct VS/MSVC setup. In that case, it is better not to ship all the dlls for each possible end machine, but the end machine is supposed to install redistributable packages.

In rare cases when the above does not suffice, you can check the error message. If that is still unclear, you can use introspection tools for debugging the issue, like dependency walker.

Disclaimer: this answer goes as broad as the question is.